# Constructing queries from user's input? php , mySQL,sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to make something like this
http://www.gsmarena.com/search.php3
to search the items from my database
and give the required result.
what would be the best way to do this in php.

EDIT:

I have an entity like '**student**' or '**mobile**' in this given case.
I want to give the user the option to get the count or details about students/phone with selected characteristics .

e.g.
how many students who have **mess bill > some value** and have **gpa < 2.0** ?

how many students with **gpa > 3** and **live on 2nd floor** in hostel?

I want to give out all the attributes to choose from.?

i understand i can use several if statements but whats the best way to do this kinda thing?
assuming i have good **C++,PHP,HTML,SQL,CSS** skills.

Comment: Sorry, this place is to ask _specific questions_ you encounter whilst implementing something. This is not a place for a general introduction to programming or the like.

Comment: @Vincent why does he needs to bind "ajax with php" in that case? Oo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know PHP and a little SQL, and don't want to use a query builder that's already out there, this is kinda what you'd end up with;

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` "
        if($_POST['price_min'] != 'doesntmatter') {
            $sql .= "WHERE `price` > '".$_POST['price_min']."'' ";
        }
        if($_POST['price_max'] != 'doesntmatter') {
            $sql .= "WHERE `price` < '".$_POST['price_max']."'' ";
        }
    }
?>
```

Basically, check if a variable is checked/selected, and if so add a WHERE clause

Comment: ...and be [pwned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). I realize this is just sample code, but I suspect the people that want an introduction won't see the SQL injection problem.

Comment: Obviously it's just an example, the code isn't safe and doesn't have enough data to be usable anyway. It's just to show how you could build an SQL query.